# Mapping JSON Object to generic Map object

Tags: java, json, hibernate, dropwizard

My current usecase involves receiving a JSON object as part of a post request, which could look something like:

```
{"employer": 1, "employee": 15}
```

From these, I then want to create a "contract" object that links my employer to my employee.

Currently, I need something like

```
@POST
public Contract createContract(ContractRequest cr) {
    Employee employee = employeeDao.getEmployeeFromId(cr.getEmployeeId());
    Employer employer = employerDao.getEmployerFromId(cr.getEmployerId());
    Contract c = new Contract();
    c.setEmployer(employer);
    c.setEmployee(employee);
    return c;

}
```

Which has several disadvantages: I need to define a ContractRequest class for the sole purpose of capturing the ids which I then pass to the employee/employer daos.

Is it possible to map the json to a generic java map object rather than having to explicitly define a class for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jackson:

```
HashMap<String,Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(string, HashMap.class);
```

or GSON:

```
String employer = root.getAsJsonObject().get("employer").getAsString();
```